# Custom domain with blogger

Tags: dns, hosting, blogger

I use blogger for a while and want to swap to a custom domain, the question is, do I need a hosting package for my domain or I just need to purchase without hosting the domain and swap. Thanks your answers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No Marshall you just need to buy a domain name and connect it to your blog by DNS settings. I recommend you ipage domain registrar , they have excellent support staff.